# Bulma get own style isn't working in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, bulma

I use [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) is styling. However, I would like to change the `primary` color. The problem is, nothing changes. How can I change the `primary` color for the Bulma in my React application? My code isn't working for the a button `<button className="button is-primary">Button</button>`

Here the documentation: https://versions.bulma.io/0.7.0/documentation/overview/customize/

index.scss

```
@import '../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass';

$blue: #3465ff;
$pink: #ffb3b3;
$pink-invert: #fff;
$family-serif: "Merriweather", "Georgia", serif;

@import '../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/derived-variables.sass';
$primary: $pink;
$primary-invert: $pink-invert;
$family-primary: $family-serif;

@import '../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass'
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bulma/css/bulma.min.css';
import './index.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <button className="button is-primary">Button</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you ever figure this out?